# Read data from api and populate .csv bug

Tags: python

I am trying to write a script (Python 2.7.11, Windows 10) to collect data from an API and append it to a csv file.

The API I want to use returns data in json. 
It limits the # of displayed records though, and pages them. 
So there is a max number of records you can get with a single query, and then you have to run another query, changing the page number.

The API informs you about the nr of pages a dataset is divided to. 
Let's assume that the max # of records per page is 100 and the nr of pages is 2.

My script:

```
import json
import urllib2
import csv

url = "https://some_api_address?page="
limit = "&limit=100"
myfile = open('C:\Python27\myscripts\somefile.csv', 'ab')

def api_iterate():
    for i in xrange(1, 2, 1):
        parse_url = url,(i),limit
        json_page = urllib2.urlopen(parse_url)
        data = json.load(json_page)
        for item in data['someobject']:
            print item ['some_item1'], ['some_item2'], ['some_item3'] 
            f = csv.writer(myfile)
        for row in data:
            f.writerow([str(row)])
```

This does not seem to work, i.e. it creates a csv file, but the file is not populated. There is obviously something wrong with either the part of the script which builds the address for the query OR the part dealing with reading json OR the part dealing with writing query to csv. Or all of them.

I have tried using other resources and tutorials, but at some point I got stuck and I would appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Are you calling this `api_iterate` function?

Comment: What is the actual URL?  The script as you have it has a number of issues that would stop it from working.

Comment: Thanks for your help @alecxe - no, I wasn't calling it at the time i wrote this post but then I realised I should. Sorry, I'm just beginning to play with it. But it didn't change anything.

Comment: thanks @Martin Evans, the actual url is [link](https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_osoby). I realise the script is crap, otherwise I wouldn't bother u. I tried also approaches using 'requests' library, so far no success

Comment: Try to reduce your problem to either accessing the API or writing the CSV. Which exactly behaves unexpectedly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url you have given provides a link to the next page as one of the objects. You can use this to iterate automatically over all of the pages.

The script below gets each page, extracts two of the entries from the `Dataobject` array and writes them to an `output.csv` file:

```
import json
import urllib2
import csv


def api_iterate(myfile):
    url = "https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_osoby"
    csv_myfile = csv.writer(myfile)
    cols = ['id', 'url']
    csv_myfile.writerow(cols)       # Write a header

    while True:
        print url
        json_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        data = json.load(json_page)
        json_page.close()

        for data_object in data['Dataobject']:
            csv_myfile.writerow([data_object[col] for col in cols])

        try:
            url = data['Links']['next']     # Get the next url
        except KeyError as e:
            break

with open(r'e:\python temp\output.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
    api_iterate(myfile)
```

This will give you an output file looking something like:

```
id,url
1347854,https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_osoby/1347854
1296239,https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_osoby/1296239
705217,https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_osoby/705217
802970,https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_osoby/802970
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Martin Evans, this is excellent. I fully understand the logic behind your solution. Having said that I'm still not sure what was wrong with mine, except that it didn't work :) I quess I will have to figure it out myself.. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: em.. I tried to use your code to access another api (ofc with appropriate changes) and it seems I still don't get it, as the code does not work. Should I post it as another question or can I bother you within this thread?

Comment: It is probably better as a separate question. Chances are the json layout is different, or perhaps does not give you a "next" element, so a different solution would be needed. Feel free to link back to this one.

Comment: ok @Martin Evans it's [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288205/parsing-api-with-python-how-to-handle-json-with-bom)