# parsing API with Python - how to handle JSON with BOM

Tags: python, json, csv, encoding

I'm using Python 2.7.11 on windows to get JSON data from API (data on trees in Warsaw, Poland, but nevermind that). I want to generate output csv file with all the data provided by the api, for further analysis. I started with a script I used [for another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36102483/read-data-from-api-and-populate-csv-bug?noredirect=1#comment59848331_36102483) (also discussed here on Stackoverflow and corrected for me by @Martin Taylor).That script didn't work so I tried to modify it using my very basic understanding, googling around and applying pdb debugger. At the moment, the result looks like this:

```
import pdb
import json
import urllib2
import csv

pdb.set_trace()
url = "https://api.um.warszawa.pl/api/action/datastore_search/?resource_id=ed6217dd-c8d0-4f7b-8bed-3b7eb81a95ba"
myfile = 'C:/dane/drzewa.csv'
csv_myfile = csv.writer(open(myfile, 'wb'))
cols = ['numer_adres', 'stan_zdrowia', 'y_wgs84', 'dzielnica', 'adres', 'lokalizacja', 'wiek_w_dni', 'srednica_k', 'pnie_obwod', 'miasto', 'jednostka', 'x_pl2000', 'wysokosc', 'y_pl2000', 'numer_inw', 'x_wgs84', '_id', 'gatunek_1', 'gatunek', 'data_wyk_pom']
csv_myfile.writerow(cols)       


def api_iterate(myfile):
    while True:
        global url
        print url
        json_page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        data = json.load(json_page)
        json_page.close()

        for data_object in data ['result']['records']:
            csv_myfile.writerow([data_object[col] for col in cols])

        try:
            url = data['_links']['next']     
        except KeyError as e:
            break

with open(myfile, 'wb'):
    api_iterate(myfile)
```

I'm a very fresh Python user so I get confused all the time. Now I got to the point when, while reading the objects in json dictionary, I get a Keyerror message associated with the 'x_wgs84' element. I suppose it has something to do with the fact that in the source url this element is preceded by a U+FEFF unicode character. I tried to get around this but I got stuck and would appreciate assistance.

I suspect the code may be corrupt in several other ways - as I mentioned, I'm a very unskilled programmer (yet).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the key with the unicode character:

To know how to do it, one easy way is to print the keys:

```
>>> import requests
>>> res = requests.get('https://api.um.warszawa.pl/api/action/datastore_search/?resource_id=ed6217dd-c8d0-4f7b-8bed-3b7eb81a95ba')
>>> data = res.json()
>>> records = data['result']['records']
>>> records[0]
{u'numer_adres': u'', u'stan_zdrowia': u'dobry', u'y_wgs84': u'52.21865', u'y_pl2000': u'5787241.04475524', u'adres': u'ul. ALPEJSKA', u'x_pl2000': u'7511793.96937063', u'lokalizacja': u'Ulica ALPEJSKA', u'wiek_w_dni': u'60', u'miasto': u'Warszawa', u'jednostka': u'Dzielnica Wawer', u'pnie_obwod': u'73', u'wysokosc': u'14', u'data_wyk_pom': u'20130709', u'dzielnica': u'Wawer', u'\ufeffx_wgs84': u'21.172584', u'numer_inw': u'D386200', u'_id': 125435, u'gatunek_1': u'Quercus robur', u'gatunek': u'd\u0105b szypu\u0142kowy', u'srednica_k': u'7'}
>>> records[0].keys()
[u'numer_adres', u'stan_zdrowia', u'y_wgs84', u'y_pl2000', u'adres', u'x_pl2000', u'lokalizacja', u'wiek_w_dni', u'miasto', u'jednostka', u'pnie_obwod', u'wysokosc', u'data_wyk_pom', u'dzielnica', u'\ufeffx_wgs84', u'numer_inw', u'_id', u'gatunek_1', u'gatunek', u'srednica_k']
>>> records[0][u'\ufeffx_wgs84']
u'21.172584'
```

As you can see, to get your key, you need to write it as `'\ufeffx_wgs84'` with the unicode character that is causing trouble.

*Note: I don't know if you are using python2 or 3, but you might need to put a `u` before your string declaration in python2 to declare it as unicode string.*

Comment: Thank you @Cybril, I already tried that. As stated before, I'm using Python 2.7.11. I tried to chanfe 'x_wgs84' to '\ufeffx_wgs84' but this didn't resolve the problem. The error response also was exactly the same. I'm not sure what you mean by putting 'u' before string - do you mean something like 'u'feffx_wgs_84' or 'u'\feffx_wgs_84'? This doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Look at my example. The u is to put before the quote.

Comment: Sorry @Cybril, now I get it. This indeed changed something, now I get error at line 7 of the code (the url definition), saying: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 0: ordinal not in range (128) :) Maybe it's because you used requests, which, as I've read, automatically handles some encoding issues..

Comment: Oh yeah, with urllib you need to decode the result as UTF8. (data.decode("utf8"))

Comment: okay @Cybril so I should write the troublesome key as u'\ufeffx_wgs84' and then after the 'data = json.load(json_page)' insert 'data.decode("utf8")'?